# Vertical Alignment of SVG in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a problem with inline SVG alignment. I have created a button with some text and an SVG. And while the alignment works correctly when the SVG is at least as big as the text it fails when the SVG height is smaller than the text.

I have created a test case with a two-colored background button to indicate where exactly the middle is. You can see if you look closer that the second case is not perfectly aligned because the height of the SVG is less than the one from the text.

Is there any way to fix this? Doing it some other way (no js please)?

Test case: https://goo.gl/KYDKGH

Comment: I can't see the issue you describe in your fiddle. what browser(s) are you seeing the issue in?

Comment: Chrome latest version. I'm on a Mac Retina. It's very subtle but it's there.

Comment: Is it the font? fonts render differently in different engines. also, if you haven't specified a font, you'll get the default, which varies according to browser and o/s.

Comment: The SVG is the problem not the text

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[**jsfiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/5kp2twuf/) - You can use `position:relative` on the container and `position:absolute` on the objects like this:

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
```

The `top: 50%` moves the object to the container's vertical center picking the top of the object as reference (not its center), so the `transform: translateY` moves it a distance of 50% of it's size upwards to let it exactly on the middle of the container (by the objects center).

*ps: the `text-align:center;` `left:0;` `right:0;` and `margin:auto` are for horizontal align.*

[**jsfiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/53c9nurz/) - Or use `display:flex` on the container with `align-items` to vertical align the content like this:

```
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */  
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

*ps: the `justify content` is for horizontal align.*

Comment: In the first solution, if there is a background, a property `top: 50%` of it breaks. The second, perfect.

Comment: I agree with comment using `top: 50%` is not the preferred  solution...